# Is there a way to force a template to get translated to a certain language without passing RequestContext?

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization

I'm rendering a template with a management command (something I need
for producing documentation in my native language). So I've no request
object, so no RequestContext. Is there a way I can force the template
rendering process to lookup translation strings from a particular
language other than English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else needs something like this. You need to do the following before rendering the template:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate(cur_language)
```

where cur_language is the language code for the language you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` directly in your management command.

Comment: No I didn't, but activating the translation for the language worked.